# getting Error-ERROR running force:org:create: The request to create a scratch org returned an unexpected status

Tags: deployment, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

getting below error while creating scratch org-
ERROR running force:org:create:  The request to create a scratch org returned an unexpected status

I am using this command-
**sfdx force:org:create -f config/template-scratch-def.json -a MyScratchOrg -d 30 -v DevHub**

by using same i have created scratch org previously

Comment: Try adding --json to command

Comment: Are you running this command from behind a proxy or firewall?